# WPF - Databind slider value to StoryBoard?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, animation, expression-blend, storyboard

I'm trying to create a sound volume control and for that I've created a storyboard which is animating the volume visually. And I've put this inside an common slider control. And I want to databind the value of the slider directly to the storyboards timeline position. If the slider is value 0, then the storyboard should be at 00:00 etc, all th way up to the top. Is this possible?

This is the code of the control. The Storyboard animation is in here.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="SoundControl_Animation">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="path3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.005"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="0"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="path2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="path1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.495"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="51.333"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid x:Name="GridRoot" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <!-- TickBar shows the ticks for Slider -->
                            <TickBar Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="TopTick" Height="4" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Placement="Top" Fill="{DynamicResource GlyphBrush}"/>
                            <Border Grid.Row="1" Margin="0" x:Name="Border" Height="4" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2"/>

                            <!-- The Track lays out the repeat buttons and thumb -->
                            <Track Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PART_Track">
                                <Track.Thumb>
                                    <Thumb Style="{DynamicResource SimpleSliderThumb}"/>
                                </Track.Thumb>
                                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton Style="{DynamicResource SimpleScrollRepeatButtonStyle}" Command="Slider.IncreaseLarge"/>
                                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton Style="{DynamicResource SimpleScrollRepeatButtonStyle}" Command="Slider.DecreaseLarge"/>
                                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            </Track>

                            <TickBar Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="BottomTick" Height="4" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Placement="Bottom" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Path Stretch="Fill" Data="F1 M-65.067448,318.22277 C-65.067448,318.22277 -58.87652,318.2416 -58.87652,318.2416 -58.797256,318.31822 -54.599352,312.8803 -54.599352,312.8803 -54.599352,312.8803 -54.601205,330.97579 -54.601205,330.97579 -54.601205,330.97579 -58.83846,325.45217 -58.83846,325.45217 -58.83846,325.45217 -64.980101,325.3728 -64.988066,325.38226 -65.018879,325.41884 -65.067448,318.22277 -65.067448,318.22277 z" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stroke="{DynamicResource DrawBrush_IconStroke}" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="{DynamicResource DrawBrush_Std_Button_HighlightPatch_MouseOver}" x:Name="path" Width="15" Opacity="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Height="20"/>
                        <Path Margin="20.671,14,26.662,14" Fill="{x:Null}" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="2" Data="M75.569117,15.851553 C75.569117,15.851553 85.628643,23.181896 75.250364,31.167364" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="4" Grid.Column="0" Height="10" Stroke="#FF666666" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment" x:Name="path1"/>
                        <Path Margin="25.51,9,19.823,9" Fill="{x:Null}" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="2.5" Data="M75.569117,15.851553 C75.569117,15.851553 85.628643,23.181896 75.250364,31.167364" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="20" Stroke="#FF848484" x:Name="path2"/>
                        <Path Margin="0,4,12.156,4" Fill="{x:Null}" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3" Data="M75.569117,15.851553 C75.569117,15.851553 85.628643,23.181896 75.250364,31.167364" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="8" Height="30" Stroke="#FFB9B9B9" x:Name="path3"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="TopLeft">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="TopTick"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="BottomRight">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="BottomTick"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="Both">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="TopTick"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="BottomTick"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" TargetName="Border"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBorderBrush}" TargetName="Border"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <!-- Use a rotation to create a Vertical Slider form the default Horizontal -->
                        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" TargetName="GridRoot">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <!-- Track rotates itself based on orientation so need to force it back -->
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_Track" Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

And the control itself it put on the Canvas like this:

```
<Slider Margin="47.75,9.75,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource btn_SoundVolumeSlider}" Grid.Column="3" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SmallChange="0" TickFrequency="0" Value="3"/>
```

Comment: Anything? I'm really at a blank here. I just know a little bit of Visual Basic and that's about it. Can someone give me a small hint of what to do next? I mean, I've got the storyboard and its XAML code. And the storyboards got values. Now, in Visual Studio, I could've probably just binded the values directly togehter by referencing to the namespace and it's control binded to. 

I don't even know the correct syntax to use here.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you plan to achieve. The point is that property binding should be performed across items on the visual tree. If you show the animation I can tell how is the proper way to bind the animation and the slider value.

For example, if your animation is a turning knob the way to do it is binding the slider value through a converter to the rotation angle of the item you want to animate. But, as I said, it depends on your animation. Show it, even a JPEG, and I can tell more details.

Comment: Ok, I've uploaded a JPEG for you to look at here:
http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/396/slidern.jpg

As you can see, I've inserted a slider control from the SimpleStyles.xaml and created a copy. I've grouped the default Grid within the control - into another Grid and put the existing content into the second column. Just to make room for the sound icon and it's animation. 

Then I created a storyboard where 00:00 represent the lowest sound volume, up to 1 second, which represent the volume at the max. I could of course create even more keyframes if that's necessary. :)

Comment: Anyone? I've been searching everywhere but can't find any info on storyboards like this

Answer (score 0):

Old, I know, but I've seen this question asked in tons of places.  Hoping this answer will help someone else.

From MSDN: **How to: Set a Property After Animating It with a Storyboard**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493.aspx

You need to remove the storyboard from the object and manually set its value to the ending value of the animation.